# Why did Tallahassee shoot his alcohol bottle?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, zombieland-double-tap

In *Zombieland Double Tap* (2019), Tallahassee tossed his alcohol bottle up in the air, aimed his gun quickly and shot it, then turned and proceeded to kill the zombie:

> Columbus: It was good. **You shot your alcohol with your gun**.

Why did Tallahassee shoot his alcohol bottle?

Comment: It looks like he just didn't really think that through... Not atypical for the character.